# Spring SessionRepositoryFilter is not applied to forwarded requests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

I'm using Hazelcast to store user sessions. Requests pass through the `SessionRepositoryFilter`, but if there's an error then the request is forwarded to */error*. The forwarded request does not pass through that filter, so tomcat creates a new session with a new ID (not a UUID like the Hazelcast session ID), and responds with a set-cookie header telling the client to change their session ID to this new, wrong one. When the client makes its next request, Hazelcast does not recognise the tomcat session ID and so responds 401 unauthorized.

Spring's [`AbstractFilterRegistrationBean#determineDispatcherTypes` method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/AbstractFilterRegistrationBean.java#L169) decides that `SessionRepositoryFilter` should not be applied to forwarded requests because it is not an instance of `org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter`. It is instead an instance of [`org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/OncePerRequestFilter.java). I think that might be a bug - they should both filter on all dispatch types.

How can I edit the dispatcherMapping of the `SessionRepositoryFilter` `FilterMap` to 31, i.e. filter all requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that our application was excluding `SessionAutoConfiguration`. If I remove that exclusion, then it imports `SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration`, which sets the dispatch types.

If for some reason you wanted to exclude `SessionAutoConfiguration`, you could instead make your `@EnableHazelcastHttpSession` class extend `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer`. That would also set the dispatch types for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can register the filter myself and set the dispatch types:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<SessionRepositoryFilter<? extends Session>> springSessionRepositoryFilterRegistration(
        SessionRepositoryFilter<? extends Session> springSessionRepositoryFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean<SessionRepositoryFilter<? extends Session>> registration =
            new FilterRegistrationBean<>(springSessionRepositoryFilter);
    registration.setOrder(SessionRepositoryFilter.DEFAULT_ORDER);
    // By default, this would only filter on DispatcherType.REQUEST
    // because it doesn't extend org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
    return registration;
}
```